# Intellij Community version can not add ruby SDK

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea

I want to open a ruby project in Intellij.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBG0i.png)
After opened the project. It is not recognized as a ruby project. Because project SDK is not set. My first problem is I can not add ruby sdk into droplist of candidat project SDKs.
 [no place not add ruby sdk into project sdks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zElKy.png)

Does any one have any idea on how to solve this problem ? Thanks

Comment: It has another IDE named `Ruby Mine`

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA Community has [no support for Ruby](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

You either need RubyMine IDE or IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate version with the Ruby plug-in installed.